# Android Java ArrayList inserting element not working

Tags: android, insert, arraylist

I have a simple Android program with one button and one textview. When the button is clicked, a number is inserted in in an ArrayList. However, it does not work. If changing to add, it works fine.

```
package test_ad.com;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test_adActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Button myB;
    int i=0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    myB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            al.set(i,10*i);//insert an Integer at index i, but not working
            i++;
            if (i == 5)
                myTV.setText(al.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList.set() is only going to work if the arraylist.size() is greater then the position you are trying to set the value for.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 0):

Edited- You added int i. First paragraph no longer applicable.

The problem is that ArrayLists grow dynamically, but you need to either tell them how big to be, or tell them to grow. If the ArrayList currently has 5 elements and you try to set the item at position 10, you should get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Is there a reason you don't want to use the add() method?
If you want to keep using set(), you should also use either ensureCapacity() or size() to make sure that the ArrayList is big enough.

Both methods are documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Hello, I just want to change elements in my Arraylist. Add() method is inserting, not changing.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot change elements that do not exist. So you either need to set the length of the ArrayList when you first create it, or you need to add elements on the fly when they don't exist.